# Finding the lowest eigenvalue using VQE-like circuits

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computer

I want to find the lowest eigenvalue for the following hamiltonian using VQE_like circuits (in python), but I don't want to use quantum libraries.

\begin{eqnarray}
H &=& \frac{-3}{2} I \otimes I + \frac{3}{2} \sigma_X \otimes \sigma_X + \frac{3}{2} \sigma_y \otimes \sigma_y + \frac{3}{2} \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z
\end{eqnarray}

How can I select the ansatz? And then, how I can calculate the expectation value? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What are $X_i$, $Y_i$, $Z_i$?

Comment: Oh, that was a mistake! I fixed them.